# bash: sed does not write the pipe result to origin file

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

I am facing this strange behaviour in a simple pipe:

```
me$ echo "AAA" > tmp.txt
me$ cat tmp.txt | sed 's/A/B/g' > tmp.txt
me$ cat tmp.txt
```

The result is an empty file and not the desired "BBB" inside the tmp.txt
It works though if I chose a different file for output. some ideas? thx in advance!

Comment: not a duplicate - see my answer, which provides a different kind of solution.

Comment: @La-comadreja, I disagree; that answer (write-and-rename) *is* already given in the other post, by Etan.

Comment: @La-comadreja, ...also, the approach you're using (with a fixed temporary filename rather than one generated by `mktemp`) is open to security vulnerabilities if (as is often the case) the directory in use is writable by other users (as is the case by `/tmp`). In that case, a hostile user with write to the same directory can create a symlink to a location which they don't have access to but the account running the script _does_, and thereby trigger overwrite of an arbitrary file which the latter account owns.

Comment: This is also enough of a FAQ to be in the BashPitfalls list: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
sed 's/A/B/g' tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
mv tmp2.txt tmp.txt
```

The first line writes the contents of the file, with the relevant string replacement, to a new file.  The second line moves the new file to the location of the old file, overwriting the old file.

Answer (score 0):

To change a file in place, use `sed -i`:

```
$ echo "AAA" > tmp.txt
$ sed -i 's/A/B/g' tmp.txt
$ cat tmp.txt
BBB
```

The above uses GNU `sed` syntax.  If you are using Mac OSX (BSD), use:

```
sed -i '' 's/A/B/g' tmp.txt
```

#### Discussion

From the question, consider this line of code:

```
cat tmp.txt | sed 's/A/B/g' > tmp.txt
```

`cat tmp.txt` attempts to read from `tmp.txt`.  When the shell sees `> tmp.txt`, however, it truncates `tmp.txt` to an empty file in preparation for input.  The result of something like this is not reliable.

`sed -i` by contrast was explicitly designed to handle this situation. It completely avoids the conflict.

If you like, `sed -i` can create a back-up of the original file.  With GNU `sed`, use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/A/B/g' tmp.txt
```

With BSD (Mac OSX) `sed`, add a space:

```
sed -i .bak 's/A/B/g' tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not prefer the 'in-place' edit to a cat or rename ?

```
sed 's/A/B/g' -i tmp.txt
```